# Unable to hit breakpoints when debugging python with pyCharm after method in arcpy

Tags: python, debugging, arcpy

I'm using PyCharm 2018.2.4 with Python 2.7. and trying to debug my code but I'm unable to hit any breakpoints after my script reaches the `arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion` or `arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion()` method (and finishes it successfully).

- Suspending all threads in the break-point doesn't work.
- The breakpoints work with other `arcpy` statements (`arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management`, `arcpy.Select_analysis`, ..).

I'm quite new to programming with Python and using the IDE. I'm not sure if it is a multi-threading problem? If yes, how do i work with it?

A very simplified script looks like this:

```
import arcpy

def import_xlsx_worksheet():
    print('Test Start')
    arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion('PathToExcel\XX.xlsx', 'PathToGDB\XX.gdb', 'Test')
    print('Test Ende')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Main - Start')
    test = import_xlsx_worksheet()
    print('Main - Ende')
```

Comment: I've seen this exact behavior too, in PyScripter and Wing IDE, with ExcelToTable and a few others.  I have not, as of yet, been able to figure out how to get around this.

Comment: The current version of PyCharm (2018.2.4) should behave correctly and hit breakpoints, but this is a known bug with Esri.  It is confirmed in Wing and PyScripter as well as older versions of PyCharm.  Table to Geodatabase is also known to cause this issue.  Tech support says they'll likely have a fix for this in the next release.  I sure hope that is the case, because I've been dealing with this for over a year now and it's maddening.  The only suggested workaround: use PyCharm 2018.2.4 or newer to debug.  If you use another IDE (like I do), you're out of luck.

Comment: I tried the new pyCharm version (2018.3.2) and it's still not working, so hopefully ESRI will fix this bug!